# Cannot call 'plot' with arguments (series[float],

Tags: pine-script

First mistake is I took some Version 3 code and pasted it into V4 and have got most of the conversion right but I know have error and I just can't figure out when I try to plot the series, getting the following error for each one:

> line 189: Cannot call 'plot' with arguments (series[float],
> color=const color, style=const string, linewidth=literal integer,
> title=literal string);

```
 //@version=4
study(title = "Study1", overlay = true)

> Blockquote


//strategy("Daily ATR Stop", overlay=true, precision=5)

smaFastLkb = input(14, minval=1, title='Fast SMA Period')
smaSlowLkb = input(28, minval=1, title='Slow SMA Period')
atrLkb = input(7, minval=1, title='ATR Stop Period')
atrRes = input("D", type= input.resolution, title='ATR Resolution')
atrMult = input(1, step=0.25, title='ATR Stop Multiplier') 


// Get the indicators
// -------------------
atr = security(syminfo.tickerid , atrRes, atr(atrLkb))
smaFast = sma(close, smaFastLkb)
smaSlow = sma(close, smaSlowLkb)


longCondition = crossover(smaFast, smaSlow)
//if (longCondition)
//    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(smaFast, smaSlow)
//if (shortCondition)
//    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

// Calc ATR Stops

float longStop = na
longStop :=  shortCondition ? na : longCondition ? close - (atr * atrMult) : longStop[1]
shortStop = float(na)
shortStop := longCondition ? na : shortCondition ? close + (atr * atrMult) : shortStop[1]
    
// Place the exits
//strategy.exit("Long ATR Stop", "Long", stop=longStop)
//strategy.exit("Short ATR Stop", "Short", stop=shortStop)
    
// Plot the stoplosses
plot(smaFast,   color=color.orange, style = line.style_dashed,  linewidth=2, title='Fast SMA') 
plot(smaFast,   color=color.purple, style = line.style_dashed,  linewidth=2, title='Slow SMA')
plot(longStop,  color=color.red,    style = line.style_dashed,  title='Long ATR Stop')
plot(shortStop, color= color.maroon,style =  line.style_dashed, title='Short ATR Stop')
```

Answer (score 3):

You were using the `style=` arguments for `line.new()`:

```
plot(smaFast,   color=color.orange, style = plot.style_circles,  linewidth=2, title='Fast SMA') 
plot(smaFast,   color=color.purple, style = plot.style_circles,  linewidth=2, title='Slow SMA')
plot(longStop,  color=color.red,    style = plot.style_circles,  title='Long ATR Stop')
plot(shortStop, color= color.maroon,style = plot.style_circles,  title='Short ATR Stop')
```

When you get a compiler error on a function call, research the function in the refman to ensure you are using it correctly. This is the entry for [`plot()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_plot). There's no dashed style for `plot()`. You can sorta simulate one using this, which makes the color invisible every second bar:

```
plot(smaFast,   color=bar_index % 2 == 0 ? color.orange : na, style = plot.style_line,  linewidth=2, title='Fast SMA')
```